# AD User folder cleanup batch script

Tags: batch-file, compare

I have a batch file I have been trying to create that would read two csv files compare them and do an action based on the differences. First file is a list of ad users and second file is a list of ad user folders on our nas.

I would like a batch file that would compare them and if there is a ad user that does not have a folder, create the folder. If there is a folder that does not have a user delete the folder. But I also would like to be able to see the results of the comparison before I let it perform the actions to make sure all is correct.

I.E.

- ad user file

  ```
  Tom
  Sam
  George
  Sally
  ```
- folder file

  ```
  Tom
  George
  Sally
  Bill
  ```

There is no folder for Sam so create it, and there is a folder for Bill but no user so delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might at least serve as a good starting point, if not immediately solve the problem:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "adusers=adusers.txt"
SET "folders=folders.txt"

COPY NUL "%adusers%.tmp" >NUL
COPY "%folders%" "%folders%.tmp" >NUL

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%U IN ("%adusers%") DO CALL :process "%%U"

ECHO Users without folders:
CALL :type "%adusers%.tmp"
ECHO.
ECHO Folders without users:
CALL :type "%folders%.tmp"
ECHO.
PAUSE

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%U IN ("%adusers%.tmp") DO CALL :addfolder "%%U"
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%U IN ("%folders%.tmp") DO CALL :delfolder "%%U"

DEL "%adusers%.tmp"
DEL "%folders%.tmp"
GOTO :EOF

:process
FIND %1 NUL || (ECHO %~1>>"%adusers%.tmp" & GOTO :EOF)
FIND /V %1 "%folders%.tmp.$$$"
DEL "%folders%.tmp"
RENAME "%folders%.tmp.$$$" "%folders%.tmp"
GOTO :EOF

:type
IF %~z1 == 0 (ECHO ^(none^)) ELSE (type %1)
GOTO :EOF

:addfolder
script to create the folder
GOTO :EOF

:delfolder
script to delete the folder
GOTO :EOF
```